# Port forwarding failing every single time despite correct settings in router (moved from stackoverflow)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

hi trying to make my web server public but am failing. I've went to many sites and read many port forwarding guides but still am unable to discern what is wrong.
port tests have failed no matter how much i tried. (had an attempted where i placed lots of port combinations in the port forwarding page but to no avail..

some additional information:
am running on raspberry pi 3 B+, raspbian. No firewall or anything.

I've tried turning off my firewall on my router completely, thinking it might be the router's firewall issue but to no avail.

public ip gotten from whatismyip (changed) : **101.251.120.22**
WAN ip (shown on ASUS router page): **172.23.118.172**
Raspberry pi local ip: **192.168.1.244**
Port my server is on: **8123**

Links:
Asus Router Port Forwarding img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZ3D.jpg
WAN general settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKMZv.jpg

netstat results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWc4f.jpg
Raspberry Pi ip: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4INoS.jpg

any help.. thanks!

P/s: moved from stack overflow. There was a comment that talked about how it's impossible to me due to my residential contract I'm prohibited to port forward or sth. Could someone explain in simpler terms? I have to get home assistant up and running for my project to work :(

Edit:have yet to try ipv6 and global addressing to make it work. Anyone have experience in this?

**SOLUTION**

Add-on to the answer marked. My network is double netted so the WAN ip and public ip shown on sites such as whatismyip is different. Getting a static ip from my ISP would help.

Comment: Your ASUS router's WAN IP is still an RFC1918 private IP address; it is not a publicly routable IP address. I don't know how much you changed your public IP, but the one you listed appears to be from an ISP in Shanghai, China. Chinese ISPs have a reputation for running their own "carrier grade" NATs and giving their customers non-routable private IP addresses. So that could be what's going on here. Another possibility to check is, if you have a broadband modem separate from your ASUS router, then your modem may be a NAT gateway router and not just a modem, so you may be doing double NAT.

Comment: i changed a few digits here and there so that might be what's affecting. But for sure is that the WAN ip shown on my Router page is different from the Public ip shown on whatismyip. I suspect this might be what's affecting me. I do have a terminal that connects to my router but i don't think it's that? since it operates as a terminal. In my case where the WAN ip on router is different than the WAN ip on whatismyip, is there anyway i could still port forward?

Comment: The fact that you are behind an ISP NAT, it doesn't actually matter if you show your public address because it is shared by thousands of customers, not only your particular router.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port forwarding is manually setting up an entry in your NAPT table to send any traffic destined to your address for a particular protocol and protocol address (port) to a particular host on the inside of your network.

The problem you have is that your router is behind an ISP NAPT router (CGN), which would also need to have port forwarding configured on it to point to your router, which is *not* configured with a public address. Your ISP will not port forward on its router for you.

For port forwarding to work from the public Internet to your router, your router would need a public IPv4 address exposed to the public Internet. Your router has a Private address on its WAN interface. The ISPs can no longer get more public addresses, so they have been hoarding them for the business customers willing to pay for the privilege of having a public IPv4 address. To do that, they started running NAT to their customers. They are supposed to use Shared address space for that, but many, like your ISP, seem to be using Private addressing, instead.

---

Residential ISPs have a clause in the terms of service forbidding you from running a service from your network to the public Internet, unless you have their explicit authorization, so the ISP is not concerned that CGN breaks your ability to expose a server to the public Internet.

Comment: Hence it is for sure to never work unless I am able to find a home server which has the router's WAN ip the same as public ip shown in whatismyip ? In that case are my only remaining options either doing what i mentioned above, ipv6 global addressing? will buying a static ip from my ISP help?

Comment: The proper thing to do would be get a business account from the ISP, with a public address. Depending on the ISP, even with a global IPv6 address, your residential ISP may block certain ports. Most residential ISPs will block you from running an e-mail server because of the problem of hacked servers running spam. Some residential ISPs will block other well-known ports. You will need to research to see what your ISP does. Obviously, it uses CGN, so you would need to try to find an ISP that does not for IPv4, but a business account is the real way.

Comment: im actually using MyRepublic (sg) . accroding to their web, if i were to use static ip, i would be able to do port forwarding. https://myrepublic.net/sg/add-ons/static-ip/ is this right? i'll drop them a call later on